# How to draw multiple images to a single canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, image, canvas, draw

I am making a website that lets users draw sketches and specify their positions and sizes; then, I save them to a database. In a different route, I want to load these images and display them on a single canvas.

I make use of the `drawImage` function for this, but what happens is that the second image gets drawn over the first image. Like in the following picture the two sketches of a `circle` and a `triangle`:

[image]

Here's how I draw the images on the canvas:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("paint");    
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function loadImages(data, targetX, targetY, targetWidth, targetHeight) {

    data = data.replace(/'/g, '"');
    targetX = targetX.replace(/'/g, '"');
    targetY = targetY.replace(/'/g, '"');
    targetWidth = targetWidth.replace(/'/g, '"');
    targetHeight = targetHeight.replace(/'/g, '"');

    data = JSON.parse(data);
    targetX = JSON.parse(targetX);
    targetY = JSON.parse(targetY);
    targetWidth = JSON.parse(targetWidth);
    targetHeight = JSON.parse(targetHeight);

    for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var img = new Image();
        var tx = parseInt(targetX[i]);
        var ty = parseInt(targetY[i]);
        var tw = parseInt(targetWidth[i]);
        var th = parseInt(targetHeight[i]);
        img.src = data[i];
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(this, tx, ty, tw, th);
        };

        
    }

}
```

The string formatting here converts the data obtained from the database (through Flask) to a JavaScript array. I have used `console.log()` on all the variables like `img`, `tx`, `ty`, `tw`, `th` and all of them have the desired values, but still on the canvas they are not getting drawn properly so I couldn't narrow down the problem.

Here's how I call the function in the HTML file:

```
{% block content %}
{% if files %}

<button id="show" onclick="loadImages(`{{ data }}`, `{{ targetX }}`, `{{ targetY }}`, `{{ sizeX }}`, `{{ sizeY }}`)">View</button>

<canvas id="paint" width="512" height="512" style="border: 5px solid #000000;"></canvas>
{% endif %}
    
<script src=" {{ url_for('static', filename='edit.js') }}"></script>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're doing async things in a sync loop. Try this..

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("paint");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

async function loadImages(data, targetX, targetY, targetWidth, targetHeight) {
  var images = {};
  data = data.replace(/'/g, '"');
  targetX = targetX.replace(/'/g, '"');
  targetY = targetY.replace(/'/g, '"');
  targetWidth = targetWidth.replace(/'/g, '"');
  targetHeight = targetHeight.replace(/'/g, '"');

  data = JSON.parse(data);
  targetX = JSON.parse(targetX);
  targetY = JSON.parse(targetY);
  targetWidth = JSON.parse(targetWidth);
  targetHeight = JSON.parse(targetHeight);

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    var tx = parseInt(targetX[i]);
    var ty = parseInt(targetY[i]);
    var tw = parseInt(targetWidth[i]);
    var th = parseInt(targetHeight[i]);
    var img = await loadImage(data[i]);
    ctx.drawImage(img, tx, ty, tw, th);
  }

}

function loadImage(src){
  return new Promise(done=>{
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = src;
    img.onload = function() {
      done(img);
    };
  });
}
```